# Dividir resultado de query em colunas

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um select que traz itens com precos, como faço para dividir o resultado em duas colunas:
 Exemplos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero deixar da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Seguem meu código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>TABELA OFERTAS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="dist/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url("img/fundo.jpg");
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>    
</head>
<body nload="toggleFullScreen()">
    <div class="container">
        <br>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img src="img/logo.png" style="width: 150px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        <h3>OFERTAS</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <?php
        include 'data/conexao.php';
        $listaProdutos = "SELECT * FROM prod_imp";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $listaProdutos);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php echo "<h3>". $row["prod_imp_nome"] ."</h3>"; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <?php echo "<h3> R$" . str_replace('.', ',', $row["prod_imp_preco"] ). "KG </h3>"; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>                              
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

A ideia seria,a cada 10 produtos criar uma nova coluna.

Comment: @sam Não, será sempre duas colunas

Comment: @sam sabe como poderia implementar isso no código ?

Comment: Talvez seria melhor dividir por 2 colunas quando for acima de 1, não?

Comment: @sam pode ser também

Comment: @sam Isso mesmo, obrigado, poste sua resposta para poder marcar por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Só observando um erro na sintaxe no `onload` do body:

```
<body nload="toggleFullScreen()">
```

Também tem um fechamento `</div>` sobrando após o `while`.

---

No mais, para dividir o resultado em duas colunas `col-md-6` você pode obter o número de resultados com `$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);` e dividir por 2. Verifique se o resultado é par com `$numrows%2`. Se não for par, a primeira coluna terá 1 linha a mais.

Criei duas variáveis `$media` (resultado da divisão por 2) e `$conta` (irá contar as linhas escritas e comparar com `$media`). Quando uma variável for igual a outra, será fechada a coluna anterior e criada uma nova.

```
<div class="container">
   <br>
   <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
               <img src="img/logo.png" style="width: 150px;">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
               <h3>OFERTAS</h3>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <br>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
   <?php
   include 'data/conexao.php';

   $listaProdutos = "SELECT * FROM prod_imp";
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $listaProdutos);
   $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
   $media = floor($numrows/2);
   $maxrow = $media;
   $conta = 1;
   if($numrows%2 != 0) $maxrow = $media+1;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   ?>
         <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
               <?php echo "<h3>". $row["prod_imp_nome"] ." R$ ". str_replace('.', ',', $row["prod_imp_preco"] ). "KG</h3>"; ?>
            </div>
         </div>
   <?php
      if($conta == $maxrow){
   ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
   <?
      }
      $conta++;
   }
   ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```